# react-smartbanner does not seem to work on iOS Safari with the standard example code

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, smartbanner

The code doesn't seem to work on iOS Safari browsers. I am not that conversant with React, so please excuse me if I am making any obvious mistakes. The code is pretty much the example given in the readme. Also, the code works fine on iOS Chrome browser. It doesn't work on Safari. Any thoughts?

Also, what is the right way to pass the'force' property? I tried the following and it throws a type error.

force={'(android,ios)'}

```
...
//@ts-ignore
import SmartBanner from 'react-smartbanner';
import 'react-smartbanner/dist/main.css';

ReactDOM.render(<SmartBanner title={'Sleekfin'} daysHidden={0} daysReminder={0}/>,
            document.getElementById('appinstall'));
...
```